# RangeError: Invalid value: Not in range 0..1114111, inclusive: -1 when trying to use upgrade command

Tags: dart, uncaught-exception, aqueduct

aqueduct db upgrade....
-- Aqueduct CLI Version: 3.3.0
-- Aqueduct project version: 3.3.0-b1
*** Uncaught error
    RangeError: Invalid value: Not in range 0..1114111, inclusive: -1
  **** Stacktrace
  * #0      StringBuffer.writeCharCode (dart:core-patch/string_buffer_patch.dart:76:9)
  * #1      PostgreSQLFormat.substitute (package:postgres/src/substituter.dart:83:29)
  * #2      Query.sendExtended (package:postgres/src/query.dart:61:38)
  * #3      _PostgreSQLConnectionStateIdle.processQuery (package:postgres/src/connection_fsm.dart:182:9)
  * #4      _PostgreSQLConnectionStateIdle.awake (package:postgres/src/connection_fsm.dart:168:14)
  * #5      _PostgreSQLExecutionContextMixin._enqueue (package:postgres/src/connection.dart:399:67)
  * #6      _PostgreSQLExecutionContextMixin.query (package:postgres/src/connection.dart:318:12)
  * #7      PostgreSQLPersistentStore.execute (package:aqueduct/src/db/postgresql/postgresql_persistent_store.dart:153:37)
  * 
  * #8      PostgreSQLPersistentStore.schemaVersion (package:aqueduct/src/db/postgresql/postgresql_persistent_store.dart:216:26)
  * #9      CLIDatabaseUpgrade.handle (package:aqueduct/src/cli/commands/db_upgrade.dart:28:52)
  * #10     CLICommand.process (package:aqueduct/src/cli/command.dart:159:20)
  * 
  * #11     CLICommand.process (package:aqueduct/src/cli/command.dart:135:12)
  * #12     CLICommand.process (package:aqueduct/src/cli/command.dart:135:12)
  * #13     main (file:///C:/Users/khalid/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/aqueduct-3.3.0/bin/aqueduct.dart:9:27)
  * #14     _startIsolate. (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:299:32)
  * #15     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's a breaking change in dart 2.8. downgrade to dart 2.7

Comment: I couldn't get it downgraded via my Linux distro and I found it tricky to get to the latest 2.7 release, so for anyone else looking for this, the url to it is https://storage.googleapis.com/dart-archive/channels/stable/release/2.7.2/sdk/dartsdk-linux-x64-release.zip

Comment: Indeed this is the only version that works , and without any dependency_overrides..

Answer (score 1):

Another solution that worked best for me is to override the postgres dependency on aqueduct:

```
dependencies:
    aqueduct: ^3.3.0+1
    # other dependencies

dependency_overrides:
    postgres: ^2.1.1
```

This was also suggested [in their official GitHub issues](https://github.com/stablekernel/aqueduct/issues/810) for another postgres related issue

Comment: `aqueduct db upgrade` will still fail with this workaround

Comment: Apparently 4.0.0-b1 sorts the issue

Comment: @JorgeBarroso what dart version are you using with this dependency_overrides ? does `aqueduct db update` works for you? I tried 2.8 and it fails with `RangeError`. 2.7 works 100%